# How to find __tokens__ in a string without using RegEx in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following:

`The __animal__ jumped over the __object__`

I'd like to write a concise method in C# that returns `animal` and `object`.  How can this be done without RegEx?  A dirty solution would be to iterate through the characters one by one until we find a `__` and then build a string until we find the closing `__` - but I'm looking for a more elegant approach.

Comment: So you don't want to use Regex, or iterate through the characters of a string, is there any good reason for that?  Do you have any more unnecessary restrictions?

Comment: @maccettura Regex is unreadable and iterating through characters is inelegant.  There's nothing wrong with seeking out clean, maintainable solutions.

Comment: "clean, maintainable solutions"... so Regex?

Comment: @maccettura if you're a robot, sure.

Comment: `IndexOf` comes to mind or `Split().Replace()` function as well.. but doesn't sound like @user666 has done any viable research or tried anything on their own..DownVoting this one

Comment: Your post has repeated underscores: `__` not `_`, yet in your post you say "iterate through the characters one by one until we find a __" which is impossible since `__` is two characters, not one

Comment: Curious why you think iterating through characters is “inelegant”. That's a pretty common and scalable method of parsing strings.

Comment: You are going to have to iterate in some fashion. Even if you make the words a collection and use linq.. the framework is just iterating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to iterate in some form - if you don't want to use regex.

```
    string text = "The __animal__ jumped over the __object__";
    List<string> words = text.Split(' ').ToList();
    words = words.Where(x => x.StartsWith("__") && x.EndsWith("__")).ToList();
```

You can use extensions of IEnumerable.to search, like above. but the framework is technically iterating.

Comment: I worry about OP if they think this is "more readable" then a 7 character Regex pattern